# Bind javascript with GridView button dynamically

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I've been trying to do this for the past hour and still got nothing. I'll try to explain it so please stay with me:

I'm trying to create a sort of summary shopping cart by creating an HTML table using javascript and adding rows every time an item is selected from the gridview.

I have a gridview with a TemplateField containing a button. The gridview looks like this:

```
Property | Quantity | Order | Action
Pencil | 10 | (textbox) | (button)
Pen | 5 | (textbox) | (button)
```

Supposedly, the button has an onclientclick event which will insert a new row to the HTML table (summary shopping cart).

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
        function addRow(tableID,property,order) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        cell1.innerHTML = property;

        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell2.innerHTML = order;

    }
```

I don't know how to bind this javascript to the (button) in my GridView though. I can't bind it on the DataBound event because I'll have to pass the value of (textbox).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like you need jquery [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to make this happen. After adding a class name to the button field, and assuming  'grid1' is the id name of your grid, The way this would work is:

```
$('#<%=grid1.ClientID %> .buttonClassName').live('click', function(){
     var next = $(this).closest('tr');// this line should find the previous tr

     next.after('<tr><td>first cell</td><td>Second Cell</td></tr>');
 });
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I'll try this when I get back. BTW, I did a quick search and found out that live is discontinued?

Comment: Thanks, this works. But how could I pass some variables from the GridView cell to the javascript? For example, I wanted to change "first cell" in the code with a Text inside a certain row in GridView.

Comment: For your first comment, you're right its being replaced by .on() which I have no experience with yet, but I am not understanding your second comment/question

Comment: This answer is for people using jquery version pre 1.7 if using 1.7+ then look into using .on() instead of .live()

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to attach the event after the gridview is rendered? Is it possible for you to use the jQuery?

http://forums.asp.net/t/1194696.aspx

The above solution might help you.The idea is to pass the grid and rowindex to javascript method when button clicked.In the javascript method using rowindex we can navigate to the desired cell and get the control.we can use jquery instead javascript in addRow then ,which will simplify the code.

Comment: yes jquery is also an option. I don't think I can attach it after rendering, because the user can input value in the (textbox) in the gridview, so I guess the only way is executing the javascript after the (button) is clicked. That's what I can't seem to do.